# Delete/Re-upload Youtube Video - Affect on Youtube/Google search results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a youtube video collection with information that is relevant for only 1 year. Once the year elapses, i need to refresh the video with updated info. I'd prefer not to have lots of year specific videos online. So my preference is to delete the video and then re-uploaded it.

What affect will this have you youtube video rankings and google search result rankings? Is there a way to preserve these when deleting/re-uploading a video?

Comment: You are going to loose everything plus the people will see broken links in search results. It is still better to create one per year and just update the description on all videos with the list of other related videos. that way the search bots can archive the other videos

Comment: I've found the api doco. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update. Am i correct in that you can only update video meta and not the video itself?

Comment: Yes, only the meta and not the actual video.

Comment: If you have "Company Event 2014" and you want to add a new "Company Event 2015", instead of deleting "Company Event 2014", just add a new video "Company Event 2015". Edit the description of "Company Event 2014" and add a link to "Company Event 2015". Google crawlers will index both video  and no broken links

Comment: That will be my solution thanks. I agree that this is the most optimal solution.

Comment: Another option would be to create a playlist with a single video in it, and circulate/publish the URL for the playlist. Then, in the next year, you can remove that video from the playlist and add your new video to the playlist, but the playlist URL will still stay the same.

Comment: That will work but it will make people frustrated if they bookmarked the video. I have no idea if you can prioritize one video above the rest.